# Is $\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{2})$ increasing or decreasing over $[0;\frac{\pi}{2}]$?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

When I used trigonometric transformation of $\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{2})$ which it is $\sin x$ the function is increasing in $[0;\frac{\pi}{2}]$ , But when we use theorem of composition of two function we have $\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{2})=(\cos \circ h)(x)   $ such that $h(x)= x-\frac{\pi}{2}$ is increasing function in $[0;\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and cos is decreasing function in $[0;\frac{\pi}{2}]$ then composition of two functions one is increasing and the second is decreasing the result is decreasing function , How this  contradiction ?

Is $\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{2})$ increasing or decreasing over $[0;\frac{\pi}{2}]$ ?

Comment: $x\to x-\pi/2$ is just a translation. That is, you are looking at $\cos t$ for $t\in[-\pi/2,0]$, where you should know what happens. The flaw in your composition is that the image of $[0,\pi/2]$ by $x\to x-\pi/2$ is **not** $[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: A composition $g\circ h$ is increasing on a set $I$ if $h$ is increasing on $I$ and $g$ is increasing on $h(I)$. In your case, $h(I)=[-\frac{\pi}{2},0]$ where $\cos$ is indeed increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\cos(0-\pi/2)=0$ and $\cos(\pi/2-\pi/2)=1$, the only possibility is that the function is increasing.

Notice that the function $x\mapsto x-\pi/2$ is increasing and takes the interval $[0,\pi/2]$ onto the interval $[-\pi/2,0]$ over which the cosine function is increasing.

In other words, if $x\in[0,\pi/2]$ you will be computing the cosine of an angle in $[-\pi/2,0]$, so the fact that the cosine is decreasing over $[0,\pi/2]$ is irrelevant.